# Re-enable wifi hardware

Tags: networking, wireless

What I did was this:

```
nmcli con delete uuid <uuid>
```

where `uuid` of wlo1 was specified. This disabled the wireless network hardware.

The command `sudo lshw -class network` outputs:

```
 *-network DISABLED                                                                                                                                                                                              
   description: Wireless interface                                                                                                                                                                            
   product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter                                                                                                                                                           
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.                                                                                                                                                                    
   physical id: 0                                                                                                                                                                                             
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0                                                                                                                                                                                 
   logical name: wlo1
   version: 00
   serial: 74:df:bf:85:45:03
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.13.0-37-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1100000-b1103fff
```

This shows that network is disabled. How do I enable it?

Comment: To turn on your wireless card `sudo iwconfig wlo1`. Or if you have to login again : `sudo iwconfig wlo1 essid <your ssid> <your wifi key>`

Comment: @PaulBenson `sudo iwconfig wlo1` outputs `wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
` which clearly says that wifi is not enabled to scan for any networks to connect to.

Comment: If you type command `nmcli device show` does it identify your wifi interface wlo1 (General Device) , MAC No. (HWADDR) and SSID (General Connection)?

Comment: Please try: `sudo ip link set wlo1 up` Any errors or warnings to post?

Comment: @chili555 It worked! You may post it as the answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you re-enable the wireless with the terminal command:

```
sudo ip link set wlo1 up
```

You should be all set.